# How to convert Java String "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy"date type to Java util.Date "yyyy-MM-dd"

Tags: java, date, datetime

My source date type is `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy`. For example, `Sat Dec 12 00:00:00 KST 2020` But my target date type is Java Date type with format `yyyy-MM-dd`. So I make the method which convert Java String type `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy` to java util object.

```
private static Date getDate(String beforeDate) throws Exception{
        
        SimpleDateFormat readFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.US);
        Date rdate = readFormat.parse(beforeDate);
        
        SimpleDateFormat writeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US); 
        String format = writeFormat.format(rdate);
        
        System.out.println(format);
        
        return writeFormat.parse(format);
    }
```

`System.out.println(format)` line prints the right values which I expect.

```
2020-12-12
2020-12-12
2013-01-01
```

But the type of return values is wrong. The return value from the method seems not to be influenced.

```
System.out.println(getDate("Sat Dec 12 00:00:00 KST 2020"));
```

The above line prints `Sat Dec 12 00:00:00 KST 2020` again. I have no idea which codes are wrong in converting Java date type.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `ZonedDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Given that you want that output, you may convert to `LocalDate`. It prints like `2020-12-12` (always).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## tl;dr

```java
ZonedDateTime
.parse( 
    "Sat Dec 12 00:00:00 KST 2020" ,
    DateTimeFormatter
    .ofPattern( "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz uuuu" )
    .withLocale( Locale.US )
)
.toLocalDate()
.toString()
```

> 2020-12-12

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

You are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes. Never use `Date`, `Calendar`, or `SimpleDateFormat`.

You said:

> my target date type is Java Date type with format yyyy-MM-dd.

Apparently, you expect `Date` to hold a date. It does not. The `java.util.Date` class represents a moment, a date with time-of-day as seen in UTC. The `java.sql.Date` class pretends to hold only a date, but it too actually contains a date with time-of-day as seen in UTC.

Among the many problems with `java.util.Date` class is the behavior of its `toString` method. That method dynamically applies the JVM’s current default time zone while generating text. This anti-feature may contribute to your confusion.

## `LocalDate`

Instead you should be using `java.time.LocalDate` to represent a date-only value without a time-of-day and without a time zone or offset-from-UTC.

## `ZonedDateTime`

First use the `DateTimeFormatter` class to parse your entire input string. This results in a `ZonedDateTime` object representing a moment as seen through the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region.

## Example code

```java
String input = "Sat Dec 12 00:00:00 KST 2020" ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz uuuu" ).withLocale( Locale.US ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse( input , f ) ;
```

From that `ZonedDateTime` object, extract a `LocalDate`.

```
LocalDate localDate = zdt.toLocalDate() ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/nkxJ2A).

> zdt.toString(): 2020-12-12T00:00+09:00[Asia/Seoul]
>
> ld.toString(): 2020-12-12

---

## About *java.time*

[image: Table of all date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), a process known as [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: Kindly inform me what is the pattern of this string value is "2020-12-18 16:04:07-06"? I use @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS". But It throws Exception.

Comment: @JosephHwang Your formatting pattern is missing codes for the offset-from-UTC appearing at the end of your input. Parse that input as a `java.time.OffsetDateTime` object in Java.

Comment: @JosephHwang `OffsetDateTime.parse( "2020-12-18 16:04:07-06".replace( " " , "T" ) )`