# Convert date format in springboot using java8

Tags: java, datetime, java-8

I receive the following date format

```
private String newDate = "Mon Apr 25 04:50:00 CET 2022"
```

How can I convert it into the following format in java 8

```
2022-04-25T04:50:00
```

Comment: Do you really want to change the time zone but not the time itself?

Comment: Why would it involve springboot?

Comment: @deHaar I want to change the time as well in the desired format

Comment: You just removed the `Z` from your desired output. That would not change the time but drop the zone / offset. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Show time only in a different format?

Comment: Yes, just to change the format.(sorry for the confusion as I am not sure of the exact value of Z here)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DateTimeParse Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62105691/datetimeparse-exception). And/or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65856109/how-to-convert-java-string-eee-mmm-dd-hhmmss-zzz-yyyydate-type-to-java-util)?

Comment: Beware when parsing three letter time zone abbreviations. `CET` may be uniquely defined, but most of the most common abbreviations are ambiguous, and when parsing one that is, you don’t know what you get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Java 8's date/time API, and more precisely the [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#RFC_1123_DATE_TIME).

There's no pre-defined formatter that matches your initial input. The closest is `DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME`, but it requires a comma after the day of the week.

To solve that, you can write your own pattern:

```java
DateTimeFormatter inputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ROOT));
String input = "Mon Apr 25 04:50:00 CET 2022";
ZonedDateTime date = ZonedDateTime.parse(input, inputFormatter);
```

The best way to represent your initial date is a `ZonedDateTime`, since your date contains zone-related information.

For your output, you can use the `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME` formatter. For example:

```java
String output = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME.format(date);
```

Comment: I suggest adding an English-speaking locale such as `Locale.ROOT` to your formatter. On my Java and default locale your code does not work without it. `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.ROOT)`.

Answer (score 3):

Almost the same answer is already given.
The given input format looks like `Date.toSTring()`, especially as weekday and month seem to be English, but might be German too. Below with `Locale.ENGLISH` (as suggested by "CET") but `Locale.GERMAN` might be better.

```
    String newDate = "Mon Apr 25 04:50:00 CET 2022";
    DateTimeFormatter formatter =
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("eee MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    ZonedDateTime t = ZonedDateTime.parse(newDate, formatter);
    System.out.println(t);
    System.out.println(Date.from(t.toInstant()));
    System.out.println(t.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME));
    System.out.println(t.toLocalDateTime().format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME));
    System.out.println(t.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC")).toLocalDateTime()
        .format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME));
```

The output variants are:

```
Mon Apr 25 04:50:00 CEST 2022
2022-04-25T04:50+02:00[Europe/Paris]
2022-04-25T04:50:00+02:00[Europe/Paris]
2022-04-25T04:50:00
2022-04-25T02:50:00
```

It is indeed best to start with a `ZonedDateTime`.

If you get input all over Europe, it would be best to use Universal Time Coordinated, Greenwich time. (But it often depends on the existing database data.)